# syslog-ng execute script on syslog pattern

Tags: linux, syslog, syslog-ng

I have a simple requirement.
I want to receive all syslog messages coming from user facility and store them in a file.  If the syslog message contains a specific pattern, I want to execute a script.

I have the following configuration,

```
destination d_logfile { file("/var/log/logile.log"); };
destination d_start_script { program("/home/ubuntu/start-script.sh"); };
destination d_stop_script { program("/home/ubuntu/stop-script.sh"); };

filter f_logfile { facility(user) and not filter(f_debug); };
filter f_filter_start { facility(user) and message("start"); };
filter f_filter_stop { facility(user) and message("stop"); };

log { source(s_network_tcp); filter(f_logfile); destination(d_logfile); };
log { source(s_network_tcp); filter(f_filter_start); destination(d_start_script; };
log { source(s_network_tcp); filter(f_filter_stop; destination(d_stop_script); };
```

when I start syslog-ng it seems to loop and execute both start and stop scripts on and off.

am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, then instead of a start/stop script, you really want to have one script that processes a sequence of messages, and a way to create this sequence. Check if you can create this sequence using the g[rouping-by() parser](http://support.oneidentity.com/technical-documents/syslog-ng-open-source-edition/administration-guide/correlating-log-messages/correlating-messages-using-the-grouping-by-parser), for example using the ${HOST}${PROGRAM}${PID} scope.
If it's not adequate, in newer syslog-ng versions you can write your own [syslog-ng destination in Python](http://support.oneidentity.com/technical-documents/syslog-ng-open-source-edition/administration-guide/destination-forward-send-and-store-log-messages/python-writing-custom-python-destinations), that probably gives you enough flexibility to get the job done (but you can also write parsers in Python if needed).

Comment: Is there a simpler way to comply with the requirement?

Comment: I guess it depends on what your incoming log messages that you want to group look like. Can you post some examples?

Answer (score 0):

As I know `syslog-ng` calls the program destination after it has been started and sends a stream to them.
I use it a similar way, but in the script have:
`if grep -qE "start" ; then <do all you needs>`

So the script runs with syslog and wait a message.